# Green's Identities

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

I am currently studying electrodynamics and I have been doing long hours of vector calculus and differential geometry in order to have a better understanding of how to do measurements involving vector fields such as the electric vector field or the magnetic etc.
My question has to do with Green's identities. I understand them mathematically and also I am aware as to how you can derivate them. But I want to understand what is the purpose of these identities in physics in particular, why are the necessary. What was the reason of them being introduced by Green?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here - is it "Why did Green introduce Green's functions," or "what is their physical significance"?

Answer (score 0):

A quite common formulation of diffraction is based on Green's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities). This idea is due to Kirchhoff, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_diffraction_formula.
It is based on the free space Green's function of the Helmholtz equation
$$\nabla^2 U + \kappa ^2 U = 0$$ that is actually solved by $\phi(x,y,z) = \frac{e^{\mathfrak j \kappa r}}{r}$ everywhere except at the origin $r=0$ where it is singular, here $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

After using Green's Theorem with this $\phi$ for the unknown wavefield $U$ you get the Kirchhoff integral, see the wikipedia article for details, or Jackson or most any EM book. The Kirchhoff integral relates the values of the wave field $U$ *inside* a closed volume to that of the values of the of the field and its normal derivatives *on* the enclosing surface.